# Find centroid of time series

Tags: r

How can the centroid of a time series be found? The centroid is used in hydrology to find the time lag between rainfall and runoff.

The centroid is also called the gravity centre of the hydrograph (the mean of the datetime weighted by the value). I give a visual example to make it clear. The most important information needed is the timing of the centroid, in the case below 08:29.

[image: Hydrograph with centroid marked with a cross]

Do anyone of have a clever idea of how this can be calculated? I use xts for my time series, but I can probably convert. Here is my example data:

```
flow <- structure(c(0, 0.1, 1.21, 3.26, 5.54, 7.5, 9.12, 9.59, 9.41, 
                 8.82, 7.89, 6.74, 5.94, 5.3, 3.67, 3.06, 2.08, 1.46, 0.95, 0.54, 
                 0.13, 0.02, 0), .Dim = c(23L, 1L), index = structure(c(1156918500, 
                 1156919400, 1156920300, 1156921200, 1156922100, 1156923000, 1156923900, 
                 1156924800, 1156925700, 1156926600, 1156927500, 1156928400, 1156929300, 
                 1156930200, 1156931100, 1156932000, 1156932900, 1156933800, 1156934700, 
                 1156935600, 1156936500, 1156937400, 1156938300), tzone = "GMT", 
                 tclass = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")), class = c("xts", "zoo"), 
                 .indexCLASS = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), 
                 tclass = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), .indexTZ = "GMT", tzone = "GMT", 
                 .Dimnames = list(NULL, structure("Flow", .Dim = c(1L, 1L))))
```

I could not find any R code to do this, neither here nor by the help of google.

Comment: Can't you just calculate it as you describe? `sum(flow * attr(flow, 'index'))/sum(flow)`

Comment: `tt <- as.numeric(time(flow)); as.POSIXct(weighted.mean(tt, flow), origin = "1970-01-01")`

Comment: Thank you very much, @pseudospin and G. Grothendieck! Both versions work well. If you make an answer below, I can mark the question as answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are the answers—thanks to @pseudospin and @g-grothendieck!

Version 1

```
as.POSIXct(sum(flow * attr(flow, 'index'))/sum(flow), origin = "1970-01-01")
```

Version 2

```
tt <- as.numeric(time(flow))
as.POSIXct(weighted.mean(tt, flow), origin = "1970-01-01")
```